# framework7: broken tab links after stripping worker IDs from URL

Tags: javascript, html, r, shiny, shinyapps

shinyMobile's [inst/framework7-5.7.8/my-app.js](https://github.com/RinteRface/shinyMobile/blob/master/inst/framework7-5.7.8/my-app.js) file has the following code chunk at the top:

```js
if (typeof workerId != "undefined") {
  var hash = window.location.hash;
  var search = window.location.search;
  var pathname = window.location.pathname;
  var newpath = pathname + workerId + search + hash;
  window.history.replaceState( {} , 'newpath', newpath);
}
```

It appends a random string (the worker ID) to the URL of the app whenever it is not run locally. E.g., https://my_domain/my_app/ becomes https://my_domain/my_app/**_w_123456**/.

This is super annoying, as it prevents search parameters (e.g., `?param=test`) from being consistently captured ([screencast video](https://vimeo.com/492431481/d617643247)).

So, I followed the solution found in this [post](https://community.rstudio.com/t/w-in-shinyapps-io-url/69893/5) and commented out the line `window.history.replaceState( {} , 'newpath', newpath);` above.

Now, worker IDs do not appear in the URL anymore. But the **links of the app's tabs** are still somehow initialized with the worker IDs! E.g., https://my_domain/my_app/**_w_123456**/#tabset-tab1. And, upon first click, because of my change above, they get updated to not containing the worker IDs (https://my_domain/my_app/#tabset-tab1), causing them to become broken!
Please see this new [screencast](https://vimeo.com/493012866/fb3a712dae).

I tried to locate the script where the tab links are initialized in [shinyMobile](https://github.com/RinteRface/shinyMobile), but I could not find it.
Maybe it is a framework7 feature?

Any tip would be greatly appreciated, as I have absolutely no clue how to solve this.

PS: I did [post](https://github.com/RinteRface/shinyMobile/issues/118#issuecomment-748593956) to shinyMobile's GitHub, but looking at the other recent issues, it seems it is unlikely I will get an answer any time soon.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to change the previous line `var workerId = $('base').attr('href');` to `var workerId = undefined;`?

Comment: I just tried, unfortunately it does not change anything :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author of the package implemented a fix: https://github.com/RinteRface/shinyMobile/issues/140#issuecomment-754765964
Many thanks to him!